# SearchView cant restore search function after closing

Tags: java, android, search, searchview

I have a structure where a search view resides at the top and a frame layout does below. SearchAFragment is the initial fragment of frame layout.

I am managing frame layout like;

```
search_box.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            changeFragment(new SearchBFragment(), id);
        }
    });

    search_box.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            changeFragment(new SearchAFragment(), id);
            //search_box.clearFocus();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I am clicking search view and then searching things and everything is all right. After searching, I click close button of search view to switch to SearchAFragment and then the problem occurs. It switches SearchAFragment but when I try to open search view and search things again, SearchBFragment never comes to front. How can I handle this problem?